# Data type issues with pandas data structures for (really) big numbers

Tags: pandas, numpy, statistics, numbers, precision

I am having issues with Python Pandas and some precision issues for a data set.
Here is the set of integers i am using as a random case found here: [link](https://jpst.it/3qV2k)

What I am trying to do is compute some statistics and cut the `Series` into bins.
Here's a driver code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
with open('dataset.txt') as source:
    parsed_data = [ int(x) for x in source.readlines() ]

sr = pd.Series(parsed_data)

q1 = sr.quantile(0.25)
q2 = sr.quantile(0.50)
q3 = sr.quantile(0.75)
  
bins   = np.unique([sr.min(), q1/2, q1, q2/2, q2, q3/3, q3, sr.max()])
labels = np.arange(1, len(bins))

binned_data, bins = pd.cut(sr, bins = bins, labels=labels, retbins=True)

#### ? ####
print(sr)
print(f"Q1 = {q1} | Q2 (median) = {q2} | Q3 = {q3}")
print(bins)
### ?? ###
for entry in binned_data: 
    print(entry)
```

Which yields:

```
Q1 = 0.0 | Q2 (median) = 0.0 | Q3 = 1589492404757.0
[0 529830801585.6667 1589492404757.0
 21267647932558653966460912964485513216]
.
.. bin numbers here BUT 
.
nan
nan
.
..
.
```

So, the my problem here is that:
The quantiles 1 and 2 (median) are 0.0. Clearly that's wrong. And that yields also incorrect binning numbers (if not for the `np.unique` the `cut` would raise an error telling me that bins must be unique!). The `dtype` of the Series is `object` and I cannot cast it to some sort of np.int..

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Checking how many of these are 0 (`(sr == 0).mean()`) shows that 54% of them are zero. It seems totally plausible that the 25% quantile and median is zero.

Comment: `The dtype of the Series is object and I cannot cast it to some sort of np.int.` You're running into the problem that integers have a limited length in NumPy. A np.uint64 can only store values up to 18446744073709551615. You have numbers bigger than that. Alternatives: 1) Convert to float. Ordinarily, that would mean a loss of precision, but all of your numbers are representable as a float without rounding. 2) Leave it as object - Python ints are arbitrary precision.

Comment: @NickODell How can I use the pandas utilities with the data type of int (Python's int) in that case?

Comment: Many of the utilities still work without doing anything special. For example, `sr - 1` works. Can you be more specific about the utility which does not work?

Comment: @NickODell No its ok they work indeed. My problem was that the binning approach returns a lot of NaN values that I cannot justify. Solved it by adding -np.inf and +np.inf as lower and upper bounds respectively.